# Signing the hash of a key with the same key

Tags: public-key, signature, dsa

Given a private signature key `sk` and a public signature key `SK`, does revealing `sk(H(SK))` (in addition to `SK`) make it more easy for an attacker to determine `sk` or to fake a signature that would appear to have been produced by `sk`? Is this scheme a bad idea - in other words, does it compromise the secuity of the signing algorithm? (It seems like this is analogous to key-dependent encryption, but for signatures, and with the interposition of a hash function in between).

If that matters, I'm using ECDSA signatures. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the confusion. A fundamental requirement of a digital signature scheme is that it doesn't leak information about the secret. Otherwise an attacker can recover the secret and forge messages which would defeat the entire purpose.

Comment: Right. I'm wondering if this would be a special case that needs to be avoided. Not that I see an attack, it's just that I've never seen this been done and I'm wondering if it's cryptographically sound.

Comment: @louism: It should be noted that your question is a good one in terms of encryption, where encrypting the key *does* lead to a different notion of security - [key dependent messaging](https://www.google.com/search?q=key+dependant+messaging)

Comment: Would people really use a signature scheme were signing a piece of public information could compromise your signing key? Wouldn't that be an obvious catastrophic deficiency?

Comment: @figlesquidge So there isn't an analogue to the "key-dependent encryption" attack for signatures ("key-dependent signatures")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, signing the hash of the public key cannot introduce a weakness on a secure signature scheme.

When we have a signature scheme, we assume that it is secure in an chosen text model, where the attacker has access to the public key, and can ask any text of his choosing to be signed.  We can see that any such scheme (such as ECCDSA, or so we believe) cannot be specifically weak this way.

This is easy to see; suppose we had a weakness that was caused by this (whether it revealed the private key, or made it easier the create a forgery).   What the attacker could do is hash the public key, and then ask that hash to be signed.  If the public key system had a weakness, this signature would reveal it, hence showing that the signature scheme didn't meet the requirements of security in the first place.